# How can I add a backslash before all spaces?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, tr

How can I put a backslash before every space, preferably by using `tr` or `sed` commands?

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
line="hello bye"
echo $line | tr ' ' "\\\ "
```

This is supposed to replace spaces with a backslash followed by a space, but it's only replacing the spaces with a backslash and not backlash+space.

This is the output I get:

```
hello\bye
```

Expected output:

```
hello\ bye
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on that?  Are you looking for a script that changes a text file?  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: `tr x ' '`, where `x` is the character you want to replace?

Comment: updated - added example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`tr` can't do multiple characters. Use one of these instead:

1. `sed`

   ```
   echo "$line" | sed 's/ /\\ /g'
   ```

   or

   ```
   sed 's/ /\\ /g' <<< "$line"
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   echo "$line" | perl -pe 's/ /\\ /g'
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -pe 's/ /\\ /g'<<< "$line"
   ```

   Perl also has a nifty function called `quotemeta` which can escape all odd things in a string:

   ```
   line='@!#$%^&*() _+"'
   perl -ne 'print quotemeta($_)' <<< $line
   ```

   The above will print

   ```
   \@\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\ _\+\"\
   ```
3. You can also use `printf` and `%q`:

   ```
   %q  quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
   ```

   So, you could do

   ```
   echo "$line" | printf "%q\n"
   ```

   Note that this, like Perl's `quotemeta` will escape *all* special characters, not just spaces.

   ```
   printf "%q\n" <<<$line
   ```
4. If you have the line in a variable, you could just do it directly in bash:

   ```
   echo ${line// /\\ }
   ```

Comment: yes this works, but does not work when wanting to replace all occurences of "a" with a backlash+space.

Comment: @sudoman I added some more options since you have the line in a variable already.

Comment: Bash's [`printf` builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) has functionality similar to `quotemeta` -- `printf '%q\n' "$line"` should do it IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

There is `AWK` missing in the list of all the possible solutions :)

```
$ echo "Hello World" | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\\ ");print}'                                                                             
Hello\ World
```